# Regex with numbers in curly brackets

Tags: regex

I got this regex:

`^\+[0-9]{12,12}$`

Can anyone explain the meaning of the two values between the curly brackets `{12,12}`?

Comment: the digits `[0-9]` must occur for min 12 and maximum 12 times. Which is same as writing `[0-9]{12}`

Answer (score 10):

`{12,12}` is a quantifier (see [Limiting Repetition section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) telling the regex engine that the preceding subpattern should repeat minimum 12 and maximum 12 times. In `^+[0-9]{12,12}$` it means that a digit within 0-9 range should be repeated exactly 12 times. The string should start with a plus, and only contain the plus + 12 digits.

> The syntax is `{min,max}`, where `min` is zero or a positive integer
>   number indicating the minimum number of matches, and `max` is an integer
>   equal to or greater than `min` indicating the maximum number of matches.
>   If the comma is present but `max` is omitted, the maximum number of
>   matches is infinite. So `{0,1}` is the same as `?`, `{0,}` is the same as `*`,
>   and `{1,}` is the same as `+`. **Omitting both the comma and max tells the
>   engine to repeat the token exactly `min` times**.

Thus, we just can use `{12}` (it is equal to `{12,12}`):

```
^\+[0-9]{12}$
```

See [demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oV5yN6/1)

Comment: In other words: simply use `{12}`

Comment: Yeah, that is just what I wanted to say at the end :)